# How to select items by their values combination

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

My example table - `fruits`.

```
+----------+----------+-------+
| FRUIT    | PROPERTY | VALUE |
+----------+----------+-------+
| APPLE    | COLOR    | GREEN |
| APPLE    | COLOR    | RED   |
| APPLE    | FORM     | ROUND |
| CUCUMBER | COLOR    | GREEN |
| CUCUMBER | COLOR    | LONG  |
| KIWI     | COLOR    | GREEN |
| MANGO    | COLOR    | GREEN |
| MANGO    | FORM     | ROUND |
| TOMATO   | FORM     | ROUND |
+----------+----------+-------+
```

Each fruit have unlimited properties, but for now from 1 to 2. Each property can have unlimited values.
I want to select all GREEN (`COLOR`) and ROUND (`FORM`) fruits (its example, in real query fruits can be filtered by dozens of properties). Valid result - apple and mango (not cucumber, not tomato, etc - only fruits who have all of desired properties).

How to write such query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the table for the properties that you want, group by fruit and check in the `HAVING` clause if all the properties are satisfied:

```
SELECT fruit
FROM fruits
WHERE (property = 'COLOR' AND value = 'GREEN')
   OR (property = 'FORM' AND value = 'ROUND')
GROUP BY fruit
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) = 2
```

Or:

```
SELECT fruit
FROM fruits
WHERE (property, value) IN (('COLOR', 'GREEN'), ('FORM', 'ROUND'))
GROUP BY fruit
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) = 2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e4516055e00aa78a1519231516fa0ebb).

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly what I want!

Comment: No reason, your answer are great. Yesterday I could not click the "Accept answer" check mark (browser bug? site bug? tried three times). Now I clicked again and check mark became green.